# Can't retrieve ParseUser with objectID in fragment

Tags: android, parse-platform

Have been trying to retrieve a specific user from **Parse.com** with its **object ID** in a **fragment**. From debugger it seems that the code of findinBackground,getInBackground or getFirstinbackground never get executed.

my **getFirstInBackground** method (In full code)

```
package com.example.jamesytl.hostel;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jamesytl on 15/4/2016.
 */
public class hosteldetails extends Fragment{
    String ownerID,email,hostelno,roomtype,desc,status,area,name;
    int price;
    ImageView image;
    TextView txtname,txtemail,txthostelno,txtprice,txtroomtype,txtdesc,txtstatus,txtarea;
    hostelwithoutparse currenthostel;
    Bundle bundle;
    ParseUser owner;
    byte[] imgByte;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hosteldetails, container, false);
        bundle = this.getArguments();
        if (bundle != null)
            currenthostel = bundle.getParcelable("item_selected_key");
        else
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        hostelno = currenthostel.getHostelNo();
        price = currenthostel.getHostelPrice();
        roomtype = currenthostel.getHostelRoom();
        desc = currenthostel.getHostelDescription();
        status = currenthostel.getHostelStatus();
        area = currenthostel.getHostelArea();
        ownerID = currenthostel.getOwner();
        imgByte = currenthostel.getImgByte();

        ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
        query.whereEqualTo("objectId", ownerID);
        query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                name = object.getUsername();
                email = object.getEmail();
            }
        });
        txtname = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDOwnerName);
        txtarea = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDArea);
        txtprice = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDprice);
        txthostelno = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDHostelNo);
        txtroomtype = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDRoom);
        txtdesc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDDesc);
        txtstatus = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDStatus);
        txtemail = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDEmail);
        image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgDHostel);


        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        txtname.setText(name);
        txtemail.setText(email);
        txtarea.setText(area);
        txtprice.setText("RM" + String.valueOf(price));
        txthostelno.setText(hostelno);
        txtroomtype.setText(roomtype);
        txtdesc.setText(desc);
        txtstatus.setText(status);
        return v;
    }

}
```

Any clue how can I make this work? Is it related to the I'm running it in a fragment causing it unable to run in background?

Comment: Can you post the full code of your fragment? we need to know where it is located in the fragment

Comment: thanks for the update. How do you know if your method isn't being called?

Comment: If you put a break point on where the method is, does the debugger stop on it?

Comment: @JoelMin ya i put two breakpoint at  "query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>()" and "public void done()". The debugger did reach the first break point but skipping the second one. So look like it never went into the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so there's nothing wrong in your actual code so far. As per your comment, the `query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>()` part does get executed, and you are wondering why the second part: `public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e)` is not executed.

The reason is that `query.getFirstInBackground()` is an **asynchronous** task, meaning it will run in the background (fetch the data in background), and when it finishes fetching, then it will execute the code in `public void done()`.

So my suggestions is that you put your code **IN** `public void done()` method, so that they are executed **AFTER** the fetching has been finished. like the following:

```
query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
            name = object.getUsername();
            email = object.getEmail();

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imgByte, 0, imgByte.length);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            txtname.setText(name);
            txtemail.setText(email);
            txtarea.setText(area);
            txtprice.setText("RM" + String.valueOf(price));
            txthostelno.setText(hostelno);
            txtroomtype.setText(roomtype);
            txtdesc.setText(desc);
            txtstatus.setText(status);
            return v;
        }
    });
```

Comment: gosh that was it. Now it finally shows the ParseUser information. Really thanks a lot for the explanation and the answer. I have another question so please correct me if I'm wrong. You mentioned that getFirstInBackground() is a asynchronous task, so does that means that my old code did actually fetch the information just that my page did not refresh to properly assign the value to the text box?

Comment: You are exactly right :) It was a matter of the timing!

Comment: argh wasted my time for this. Guess now I just have to add progress bar to  make the waiting looks more sense. Once again thank you very much for your time and teaching. Much appreciated :D

Comment: joel mind if I ask you something about many-to-many relation in parse? Searched internet and seems like very limited information regarding it

Comment: I am not really experienced in Parse though :( I would suggest that you post a question here on SO!